# What is _Layout.es5.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am working on an asp.net MVC project.

I noticed that there are 2 files in my script folder (can't remember how they got added, but I don't seem to be using them):

1. _Layout.es5.js
2. _Layout.es5.min.js

They never show up in Visual Studio, even when I choose 'Show All Files' options.

What are these files? Why don't they show up in Visual Studio? And should I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a script files are used anywhere in the project (js, css or any script/content file). You can follow the following steps:

- In visual studio press `Ctrl + Shift + I` then search for `_Layout.es5.js` or `_Layout.es5.min.js`. Use the "Find all" option for faster result
- Also do a search with partial name like `_Layout.es`
- Your file might be referenced dynamically which will not show up in the previous search. If no reference was found in the previous search then from the browse check if the file is downloaded on any page by browsing the pages and inspecting which files are downloaded.
  For example on Google Chrome open the Developer tool, Then check the `Disabled cache` and the `js` check boxes so that you can check the JS files only.

[image]